# MySQL alter table command does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a column to my existing users table but it does not work. I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned default 0 after users_id' at line 1
```

Here's my command:

```
root@localhost:test> alter table users add column users_is_active tinyint(3) not null unsigned default 0 after users_id;
```

unless I didn't spell "not null" correctly, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Could you try swapping not null and unsigned with each other?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> alter table users add column users_is_active tinyint(3) not null unsigned default 0 after users_id;

`TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED` is the type. `NOT NULL` does not belong between `TINYINT(3)` and `UNSIGNED`. Instead say `TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL` (etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Move `unsigned` closer to `tinyint`:

```
alter table users 
  add column users_is_active tinyint(3) unsigned not null default 0
  after users_id;
```